# How to secure web api in .Net 6

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am relatively new in .Net 6 and looking for all possible options to implement authentication and authorization in my Web API project. I have googled and found JWT and OAuth options. Are there any more ways to implement security in API.
In my case my consuming applications are **using SSO**. **They won't be sending user name and password so I am confused that, how will I generate jwt token authentication without user name/password**. Also as its intranet project so I **may** **not** able to use OAuth. Which one would be more suitable in my case. If you only list out few options I can dig more on google for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if consuming app is using SSO, then they are already getting JWT token from SingleSignOn Server. then you have to just validate the token with same SSO. you don't need to generate the token again in your API.

Comment: @CodingMytra how to validate it in .net code. Any suggestions or article on it please. Thanks

Comment: this [link](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/apis/aspnetcore/jwt/) provides an example how you can validate jwt token with SSO. although it is for IdentityServer but the validation remains same for any SSO. only need to provide SSO's url as authority.